# Fluent NHibernate PersistenceSpecification Component and Reference Tests

Tags: unit-testing, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, testing, components

I have two problems.

1 . FNH does not test my component correcty and I dont know why.

> System.ApplicationException: Expected
>   'DomainModel.Model.Publisher' but got
>   'DomainModel.Model.Publisher' for
>   Property 'Publisher'.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CanCorrectlyMapBook()
{
    new PersistenceSpecification<Book>(_session)
        .CheckProperty(p => p.Name, "My Book")
        .CheckProperty(p=> p.Id, 1)
        .CheckProperty(p=>p.IncludesCDDVD, true)
        .CheckProperty(p=>p.Isbn, "rder93q43949éwr")
        .CheckProperty(p=>p.IsLoaned, false)
        .CheckProperty(p=>p.Publisher, new Publisher(){PublisherHomepage = "www.google.de", PublisherName = "google"})
        .VerifyTheMappings();
}
```

}

2 . FNH does not test my reference correctly.

> System.ApplicationException: Expected
>   'DomainModel.Model.Employee' but got
>   'EmployeeProxyd6f94daa37c74be8b5ccccf40c5c23fa'
>   for Property 'LoanedBy'.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CanCorrectlyMapBook()
{
    new PersistenceSpecification<Book>(_session)
        .CheckProperty(p => p.Name, "My Book")
        .CheckProperty(p=> p.Id, 1)
        .CheckProperty(p=>p.IncludesCDDVD, true)
        .CheckProperty(p=>p.Isbn, "rder93q43949éwr")
        .CheckProperty(p=>p.IsLoaned, false)
        .CheckReference(p=>p.LoanedBy, new Employee(){EMail = "",FirstName = "Alex", LastName = "Mueller"})
        .VerifyTheMappings();
}
```

But when I test this "manually" everything works fine.

```
 ISession mysession = Helper.CreateSessionFactory(false, false).OpenSession();
            Book myBook = new Book()
                              {
                                  Author = "Hesse",
                                  IncludesCDDVD = true,
                                  DateOfIssue = DateTime.Now,
                                  Isbn = "erwe0ri",
                                  IsLoaned = true,
                                  Name = "My Book new",
                                  Publisher = new Publisher() { PublisherHomepage = "www.google.de", PublisherName = "google" },
                                  Release = new Release() { ReleaseDate = DateTime.Now, ReleaseNumber = 1 },
                                  LoanedBy = new Employee() { EMail = "", FirstName = "Alex", LastName = "Mueller" }
                              };

            mysession.Save(myBook);
            mysession.Close();
            mysession.Dispose();
```

I have verify this by looking up in the datbase ...

The PersistenceSpecification Tests run against an in-memory database sqllite and my manual "test" runs against a Sql Server 2008.

Does anybody of you have used FNH and tested a reference and a component correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you either need to implement the object.Equals() method on the relevant entities, or implement an IEqualityComparer and inject it when you construct the PersistenceSpecification.

For example:

```
public class A
{
    private int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual B B_Member { get; set; }

    public class Map : ClassMap<A>
    {
        public Map()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            References(x => x.B_Member);
        }
    }
}

public class B
{
    private int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string BString { get; set; }

    public class Map : ClassMap<B>
    {
        public Map()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id);
            Map(x => x.BString);
        }
    }

    /// remove this method to have the verification fail
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var lhs = obj as B;
        if (lhs == null) return false;
        return BString == lhs.BString;
    }
}

    [Test]
    public void Verify()
    {
        var fcfg = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.UsingFile("testdb.sqldb"))
            .Mappings(mc =>
            {
                mc.FluentMappings.Add(typeof (A.Map));
                mc.FluentMappings.Add(typeof (B.Map));
            })
            .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Execute(true, true, false));

        var sess = fcfg.BuildSessionFactory().OpenSession();

        new PersistenceSpecification<A>(sess)
            .CheckReference(x => x.B_Member, new B() {BString = "hi"})
            .VerifyTheMappings();

        Assert.Throws<ApplicationException>(
            () => new PersistenceSpecification<A>(sess, new AlwaysFalseEqualityComparer())
                    .CheckReference(x => x.B_Member, new B() {BString = "az"})
                    .VerifyTheMappings());
    }
```

Note also that the relevant FNH code for each property comparison is (compliments of reflector):

```
    internal virtual void CheckValue(object target)
{
    bool areEqual;
    object actual = this.property.GetValue(target, null);
    if (this.entityEqualityComparer != null)
    {
        areEqual = this.entityEqualityComparer.Equals(this.propertyValue, actual);
    }
    else
    {
        areEqual = this.propertyValue.Equals(actual);
    }
    if (!areEqual)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Expected '{0}' but got '{1}' for Property '{2}'", this.propertyValue, actual, this.property.Name));
    }
}
```

Certainly that that exception seems to match the ones you are experiencing.

Comment: I think this does not help, because components are no entities so they have no Ids. I have implemented the object.Equals method, but there is still the same error message for my components and reference. But it would be nice if someone can show me a simple example where one can see that the FNH API works correctly. For me it seems it does not.

Comment: I'm not sure why components not being entities would mean that implementing equals or an equalitycomparer would not help. I have provided a simple example for a reference.